# Cycle through windows in KDE 4 taskbar by shortcut?

Tags: kde, kde-4

Is there a way to cycle through the windows in the KDE 4 taskbar with a shortcut?

I want to have a *switch to next window* function on a mouse button. Therefore `Alt+Tab` is not suitable because it uses a stack for the windows. This means if hitting `Alt+Tab`, releasing the `Alt` key and pressing `Alt+Tab` again will bring up the window I had before pressing the keys the first time.

Maybe there is a solution using DBus. But I don't know how to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exposed in DBus. You can switch desktops, but not app windows. [File a bug](https://bugs.kde.org).

```
qdbus org.kde.kwin /KWin
```

This looks promising, but does something else.

```
dbus-send --dest=org.kde.kwin /KWin org.kde.KWin.circulateDesktopApplications
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sort order for windows in kde:

System settings > Window Behaviour > Task Switcher: Change "Sort order" to "Stacking order"

Then every time you hit alt+tab you will be taken to the next window rather then toggling between the most recent two.

Answer (score 0):

kde4.4 should come with window tabs, so maybe it will help you out. comes out february 9th.